# why can't omit module dependency in angular.module when define component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The main module`app.js`:

```
angular.module("myApp",["phoneList"]);
```

and I follow the [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04) to make a sperate component module named `phoneList`

```
angular.module("phoneList")
                      //^ omit the empty bracket here, cause no dependency needed
    .component('phoneList', {
        templateUrl: 'template/phone-list.html',
        controller: function (){
            this.phones = [
                {name: "iphone", snippet: "designed by apple"},
                {name: "nexus", snippet: "phone that could explode"}
            ]}

});
```

but it will complain that:

```
angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/nomod?p0=phoneList
    at angular.min.js:6
    at angular.min.js:25
    at b (angular.min.js:24)
    at Object.module (angular.min.js:25)
    at phone-list.js:5
```

When I add an empty `[]` back:

```
angular.module("phoneList",[])
     .component(//balabla)
```

things will work just fine. I checked the [API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module), it demonstrate that the dependency is optional thus could be omitted.

So what cause the problem?
[image]

Comment: Passing one argument retrieves an existing `angular.Module`, whereas passing more than one argument creates a new `angular.Module`
as you are creating `phoneList` a new module so you have to pass 2nd parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation,

> angular.module(name, [requires], [configFn]);
>
> If specified then new module is being created. If unspecified then the
>   module is being retrieved for further configuration.

It means you need to pass an empty array []. To make it work without any dependency module, you can use it as

```
angular.module("phoneList",[])
```

**Update**

if the module is already declared you do not have to pass the dependencies again. So you can use your component/controller/service/factory as

```
angular.module('phoneList').controller(...)...
```

Comment: check the snap-shot I just appended to the question

Comment: @armnotstrong module and component are two different things, when you declare a component , if the module is alreaydy declared you do not have to pass the depdencies again

Comment: thanks @Sajeetharan, now I get the point, I have a misunderstanding of the specification

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the module defined you can refer to it without the second argument. The first time you do.

So...

```
angular.module('app',[ dependencies... ]);
angular.module('app').controller(...)...
```

would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is because passing an array in the second argument tells angular to create a new instance of the module with all the dependencies mentioned. If you do not have any dependencies you have to pass a empty array in order to create a new module.

By omitting this parameter you ask angular to retrieve the existing module. And, in your code you do not have a module previously named `phoneList`. That is why it is giving you the error.